# Solubility of cholesterol in water - data not matching up?

Tags: organic-chemistry

I found two papers with solubility data for chol in water.

One says 1.8 mg/L at 30 deg C

Other says 10^-9.3 (mol fraction basis) at 25 deg C

However when I tried to convert the latter to mg/L I get:

So for 25 deg C = 10^-9.3 = 5E-10 mol/mol

5E-10 mol chol/ mol total = 5E-10 mol chol/ (1-(5E-10)) mol water = 0.99

(5E-10 mol chol/ (1-(5E-10)) mol water) *(386.65 g/mol chol / 18 g/mol water) =1.074E-8 g chol/g water

1.074E-8 g/g * (1000 g/L water) * (1000 mg/g chol) = **0.0107 mg chol/ L water**

Is there a mistake in my conversion? They seem way off for only being 5 deg difference.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A quick lookup tells me that mol fraction=moles of solute/total mole.

Let us consider the mole of cholesterol to be x.

In 1 litre of water, mass of water is 1000 grams.
Assume Mr of water to be 18 (rounded up). So, moles of water=1000/18=500/9

=> 10^(-9.3)=x/{x+(500/9)}
Solving this find x gave me x = 2.784...E-8

So, mass of cholesterol in mg is (x)(386)(1000).
This is 0.01074... mg.

As you can see my calculations matched up with yours.

I was off to Google and https://pubchem.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/compound/cholesterol#section=Solubility
 states the solubility at 30 degrees Celsius is 0.095mg/L. So, I'd say one of those papers might have stated a value under different conditions or a wrong value.